# Repeat along given axis with as_strided

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a numpy array:

```
a = array([[0., 1., 2.],
           [3., 4., 5.],
           [6., 7., 8.]])
```

which i replicate with `np.repeat` like that:

```
np.repeat(a, 3, axis=0)
```

with the result:

```
array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [0., 1., 2.],
       [0., 1., 2.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [6., 7., 8.],
       [6., 7., 8.],
       [6., 7., 8.]])
```

Can i achieve the same with `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` to avoid copying data? I need something like that also for multidimensional arrays, but i always repeat along 0-th axis...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? maybe we can help with the ultimate task that you are going to use the output for. Because, doing calculations of views of an array should be performed with caution to avoid mistakes (and probably can be done using only the original array anyways)

Comment: The resulting array can be 'read only' so i do not bother very much the safety. Such repeated arrays are used throught the software i use and i run into memory troubles. I preferred to adjust the memory efficient solution for repeating array then rebuilding the software to use original ones...

Comment: For this small example, `repeat` is quite fast, though I can see where it could give memory errors.  The equivalent `as_strided` is really a form of broadcasting, repeating a dimension with a 0 stride.  By itself it is a memory saving view, but subsequent operations can easily create full size arrays.  A (n,1)+(1,m) produces a (n,m) result (even if avoids temporary (n,m) or (n*m,) arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  You can get close:

```
n=3
out = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, 
                                      shape   = (n,) + a.shape, 
                                      strides = (0,) + a.strides
                                     )
np.shares_memory(a, out)
Out[]: True

out
Out[]: 
array([[[0., 1., 2.],
        [3., 4., 5.],
        [6., 7., 8.]],

       [[0., 1., 2.],
        [3., 4., 5.],
        [6., 7., 8.]],

       [[0., 1., 2.],
        [3., 4., 5.],
        [6., 7., 8.]]])
```

But that's not repeating in dimension 0, it's repeating everything in a new dimension 0.  And reshaping creates a copy:

```
out.reshape(-1, 3)
Out[]: 
array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [6., 7., 8.],
       [0., 1., 2.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [6., 7., 8.],
       [0., 1., 2.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [6., 7., 8.]])

np.shares_memory(a, out.reshape(-1, 3))
Out[]: False
```

You'll generally be better off using broadcasting instead, going from something like:

```
op(a_repeated, b)
```

to:

```
op(a[None, ...], b.reshape((-1, a.shape[0]) + b.shape[1:])) )
```

But that depends a lot on what `op` is (and whether it is vectorized and/or vectorizable).

Comment: `np.broadcast_to(x,((n,)+x.shape))` does the same thing, and for some reason is a bit faster than the the `as_strided`.  But for this small size `repeat` is plenty fast.